# Как заменить знак + в GET переменной

Tags: php, api, запрос, get

Как с помощью GET передать запрос чтобы вместо "+" - Пробел. Передавался запрос "%2B"

Форма/search.php/Запрос

```
Форма_

 <form action="search.php" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Поиск.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
  <input value="1" name="chank" id="one" type="radio" checked />
  <label for="one" class="switch__label">1</label>
  <input value="2" name="chank" id="two" type="radio" />
  <label for="two" class="switch__label">2</label>
  </form>

search.php_

$search=$_GET['search'];
$channel=$_GET['chank'];
$page=$_GET['page'];
include "conf/info.php";
$title = 'Результаты Поиска | '.$search;
include "header.php";
include "api/api_search.php";

Запрос_

$cs = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, "".$home."".$vapi."/search/".$chank."?api_key=".$key."&language=".$lang."&query=".$search."&page=".$page."");
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json"));
$response = curl_exec($cs);
curl_close($cs);
$search = json_decode($response);
```

Вот что отправляет из формы:

1. [http://site.ru/search.php?search=ванда+вижн&chank=2](http://site.ru/search.php?search=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD&chank=2) (не находит),
2. (замена в адресной строке "+" на "%20") [http://site.ru/search.php?search=ванда%20вижн&chank=2](http://site.ru/search.php?search=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD&chank=2) (не находит),
3. (замена в адресной строке "+" на "%2B") [http://site.ru/search.php?search=ванда%2Bвижн&chank=2](http://site.ru/search.php?search=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%2B%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD&chank=2) (Находит!)

Как в моем случае заменить + на %2B при отправке запроса?

Comment: Надо вывести $search на экран, и посмотреть глазками, что там надо заменять.

Comment: @Ипатьев Мне пробелы нужно заменить c + на %2B при GET запросе Вот get $search: Array ( [search] => Лило и стич [chank] => 1 )

Comment: Нет. Тебе нужно прочесть мой комментарий выше.